# Лучше ли sleep() чем yeld(), и если да, то чем?

Tags: java, многопоточность, sleep

Чем `Thread.sleep(1)` лучше `Thread.yeld()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Давший этот совет поверхностно разбирается в вопросе. Или вовсе не разбирается. Сравнивать эти методы не совсем корректно, у них разное назначение.

- [Thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) останавливает поток на количество миллисекунд указанное в аргументе. Если нет других потоков, готовых к работе, процессор будет простаивать.
- [Thread.yield()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield--) заявляет о намерении потока уступить выполнение другим потокам. Если есть другие потоки, готовые к работе, контекст выполнения будет переключен на один из них. Если нет, то текущий поток продолжит своё выполнение.

Важно понимать, время вызова `Thread.yield()` может измеряться наносекундами, в то время как `Thread.sleep(1)` остановит поток на миллисекунду. То есть вы можете замедлить вашу программу в сотни тысяч раз, если логика кода в переключении между потоками. С другой стороны, если логика именно в ожидании, то `Thread.yield()` вообще ничего не даст.

Comment: Давший этот совет мог иметь в виду всё что угодно, о чём автор вопроса умолчал или просто не знает. Например `Thread.sleep(n)` с разными небольшими значениями `n` можно использовать не просто для "заявления о намерении потока уступить выполнение другим потокам", а ещё и для уменьшения приоритета собственного потока. Ведь чем больше текущий поток спит, тем меньше он занимает ресурсы, необходимые и остальным потокам. Но домысливание за автора вопроса - вещь неблагодарная и неправильная. Поэтому я дал свой короткий ответ в стиле автора вопроса.

Comment: Так же вызов `Thread.yield()` является лишь рекомендацией для планировщика потоков, то есть переключение на другой поток, после такого вызова, вовсе не обязательно, а лишь более вероятно. Чтобы это проверить просто создайте два потока, в каждом из которых, в цикле, печатайте, скажем "I'm thread AAAA" или "I'm thread BBBB" и затем вызывайте `Thread.yield()`. В моих тестах видно большое число **подряд** текстов от каждого из потоков.

Comment: Тут надо добавить, что `yield` не останавливает потоки, в то время как `sleep` - останавливает текущий.

Answer (score -1):

Ничем, `Thread.sleep(1)` не лучше `Thread.yeld()`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите более развёрнутые ответы. Ответы типа "да, можно" или "нет, нельзя" без пояснений несут мало пользы спрашивающему.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/292710)

Comment: Для написания более развёрнутых ответов таковыми должны быть и вопросы. Я не могу домысливать за автора вопроса то, что он не говорил.